# c++ proper syntax for templated function of `std::vector<T>::iterator`

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I'm trying to code a template that takes iterators to any type of vector as its arguments. When I try to compile the following, it gives me a `no matching function call` error.

```
#include <vector>

struct A { int x; };

template <class T>
void process (typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin, 
              typename std::vector<T>::iterator end)
{ for(; begin != end; begin++) { /*do_something*/ } }

int main()
{
   std::vector <A> obj;
   process(obj.begin(), obj.end());
}
```

Comment: Why limit it to a container? Use a random-access iterator if that's what works.

Comment: The short version: there is no proper syntax - you can't deduce a template argument from a nested type.

Comment: Six trillion duplicates of this question.

Comment: Any special reason you don't have the iterator type itself as the template-paramter, with the underlying value-type extracted with iterator_traits ?

Comment: Should also note, this specific example is a prime candidate for [`std::for_each()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: @chris How do you do that?

Comment: @Whoz How do you do that?

Comment: @MattMunson, The standard algorithms typically take a `typename Iter` as the iterator type and spit 500 lines of errors if it isn't compatible. You can put in a `static_assert` using `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_type` or something like that if you want a good error.

Comment: @MattMunson see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** the type `T` cannot be deduced from the argument types.

**2** Why would you want to restrict the function to only accept iterators to `std::vector` elements? If you really only want vector elements, better take `std::vector<T> const&` as argument. But better simply take any iterator arguments (or any container argument).

---

**edit** okay, here is an example. You may omit the `static_assert`, when this becomes identical (apart from the return type) to `std::for_each(begin,end,do_something);`

```
template <class It>
void process(It begin, const It end)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
                             std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value,
                "arguments not random access iterators");
  for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    do_something(*begin);
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for your second solution?

Answer (score 2):

Per the OP's request, see below. you can use any valid container forward iterator that supports value references from `operator *()` I.e. a vector, deque, list, etc. This does not employ the static assert logic mentioned by chris, I leave that for you to decide.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename Iterator>
void process(Iterator start, Iterator stop)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    for (Iterator it=start; it != stop; ++it)
    {
        const value_type& val = (*it);

        // do something with val
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ar[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    process(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not just do `std::cout << (*it)`, and omit the stuff with `value_type`?

Comment: @MattMunson because I wanted you to blatantly see how your value-type is reference-able. It is just for visual (yours).